# How can i add dynamic sections withing dynamic sections in shopify custom theme developement?

Tags: dynamic, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I am developing an sections which contains dynamic sections ,
one section contain more dynamic section in it as there is no documentation about it at shopify platform

Comment: You can't have a section inside another section, however you can create blocks inside a section. [This article](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/how-to-create-your-first-shopify-theme-section) should provide a good starting point for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify provide us two type of sections

- Static
- Dynamic

1. If you are using dynamic section (which is only available at homepage) then you can only create one dynamic section at one time you cannot make nested sections.
2. But if you are trying to use the dynamic section ability just like homepage on anyother page then you can also do this.

- You only need to make a static section and use the blocks in your schema code. Is that why you can add multiple sections in any page and also reorder them just like the homepage.